# how can I use ggplot2 to visualize this data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2s2N.png)

```
first_name    last_name      party       vote
     Ralph      Abraham          R        Yea
      Alma        Adams          D        Nay
    Robert     Aderholt          R        Nay
```

I want to display this data in a plot using ggplot2. How would you suggest I do that? I keep trying things like

```
ggplot(data = voters) + stat_count(mapping = aes(x=party, y = vote))
```

but it gives me the error

```
stat_count requires the following missing aesthetics: x
```

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: please include first few rows of your data as text instead of posting it as an image

Comment: @ImranAli I edited it!

Comment: Include your data `dput(voters)` so we can reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
voters <- data.frame(party = c("R", "D", "R", "D", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "D", "R"),
             vote = c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y"))

ggplot(voters, aes(x = party, fill = vote)) + geom_bar()
```

[image: barplot]

You can't tell from this plot (because everyone voted based on party lines) but using the same code, if there were both "Yea" and "Nay" votes coming from the same party, you would get a stacked bar plot showing multiple colors.

Comment: yes, but for some reason when I run the code you wrote, I'm still getting `Error: stat_count requires the following missing aesthetics: x`. Any idea as to what the problem may be?

Comment: I ran the code from this answer without any errors. If you are seeing that error, you have not entered the code as written in the answer.

Comment: @neilfws I only ran the second part because my `voters` data frame already exists. Is the issue with my data frame?